# PayPal timeout on classic API sandbox call

Tags: paypal, sandbox

I'm using PayPal Digital Goods checkout with the classic API (signature/password API credentials). Live transactions are working but sometime between Dec 27 and Jan 7 sandbox transactions stopped working, claiming "session expired" when trying to confirm the transaction. Following is the response to the Digital Goods checkout and the confirm invocations:

```
[08-Jan-2014 20:03:06 UTC] PayPal Checkout-Calling SetExpressCheckoutDG
[08-Jan-2014 20:03:07 UTC] PayPal Checkout Result. Results = TOKEN:EC-38C423050J138841W TIMESTAMP:2014-01-08T20:03:07Z CORRELATIONID:381d15bad3eaa ACK:Success VERSION:84 BUILD:9187650
[08-Jan-2014 20:03:07 UTC] RedirectToPayPalDG Header=https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/incontext?token=EC-38C423050J138841W
[08-Jan-2014 20:03:14 UTC] PAYPAL GetExpressCheckoutDetails TOKEN=EC-38C423050J138841W
[08-Jan-2014 20:03:15 UTC] PayPal Confirm--Failed. Results = TIMESTAMP:2014-01-08T20:03:15Z CORRELATIONID:2b45bb61f3787 ACK:Failure VERSION:84 BUILD:9187650 L_ERRORCODE0:10411 L_SHORTMESSAGE0:This Express Checkout session has expired. L_LONGMESSAGE0:This Express Checkout session has expired. Token value is no longer valid. L_SEVERITYCODE0:Error
```

Note the timestamps: the error return is 9 seconds after the checkout timestamp (when the user process started).

It looks like the classic API to the sandbox is broken. Anyone else seeing this, and if so is there a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Its a different correlation or even a different session.

Comment: Yes I see that, but all I have control of is the token which is constant from checkout to confirmation.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved--my error in managing credentials.